# Modify JQuery easyTooltip to detect screen edges

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I'm using the following JQuery script to create hovering tooltips, the problem is if the tooltip gets close to the edge of the screen it doens't flip or snap to the edge.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.easyTooltip = function(options){
    var defaults = { // default configuration properties
        xOffset: 10,        
        yOffset: 25,
        tooltipId: "easyTooltip",
        clickRemove: false,
        content: "",
        useElement: ""
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
    var content;
    var url;

    this.each(function() {                  
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        var url = $(this).attr("tooltipURL");
        $(this).hover(function(e){
            if (url != "" && url != undefined) {
                content = '<span class="loadingimage"></span> Loading...';
                tooltip(content);
                $('#'+options.tooltipId).load(url, {"id":$(this).attr("value")}); 
            } else {
                content = (options.content != "") ? options.content : title;
                content = (options.useElement != "") ? $("#" + options.useElement).html() : content;
                $(this).attr("title","");
                if (content != "" && content != undefined){         
                    tooltip(content);
                }
            }

            function tooltip(content) {
                $("body").append("<div id='"+ options.tooltipId +"'>"+ content +"</div>");      
                $("#" + options.tooltipId)
                    .css("position","absolute")
                    .css("top",(e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
                    .css("left",(e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")                     
                    .css("display","none")
                    .fadeIn("fast")
            }

        },
        function(){ 
            $("#" + options.tooltipId).remove();
            $(this).attr("title",title);
        }); 
        $(this).mousemove(function(e){
            $("#" + options.tooltipId)
                .css("top",(e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")                 
        }); 
        if(options.clickRemove){
            $(this).mousedown(function(e){
                $("#" + options.tooltipId).remove();
                $(this).attr("title",title);
            });             
        }
    });

};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Comment: can u show your working page ?

Comment: It's in use on a new website i'm working on http://webcomictweets.com/ hover over any avatar or username for an example.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Tools Tooltip (+ Dynamic Plugin)](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/dynamic.html) supports this; I'd suggest you switch to use that or try implementing the code on your existing setup.

Comment: I've looked at other jquery tooltip scripts, but they all seem bloated. That one is over 7KB, the one i'm using now is 1.8KB. But one of the main things I like about the easyTooltip is I can load the tooltip content from an external php file, rather than putting all the text in a title="" tag which many of these tooltips seem to do.

Comment: You can customise an export of jQuery Tools to only the functionality you need and opt for it to be minified- I'm sure that'd lower it below 7kb. I also expect the functionality allows for the content to be abstracted externally; it's a fairly diverse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 $("#" + options.tooltipId)
            .css("top",(e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")
```

Try something along the lines of:

```
    var x = (e.pageX + options.xOffset);//start with your current setting
    //Check to see if it goes off screen
    if ((x + $("#yourdiv").outerWidth()) >= $(window).width()) {
            x = e.pageX - $("#tooltip").outerWidth();
        }
```

and then repeat for y and replace existing code of course:

```
     $("#" + options.tooltipId)
            .css("top",(y) + "px")
            .css("left",(x) + "px")
```